# Is it okay to send a 301 redirect from https (if not in use)?

Tags: redirect, seo, web-hosting, http-status-code-301

I have my website hosted on the HTTP protocol, but my hosting service provides a default page when accessed through HTTPS. Since I'm not using SSL, from an SEO perspective, which one is more correct?
a) toggle https for my website and do a 301 redirect to http://?
b) just leave it like that (default https page from the web hosting co)

Comment: SEO belongs to [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, wasn't actually aware that SE had created this forum.

Answer (score 0):

A would be the cleanest solution but it shouldn't really matter. Who, besides yourself, will be trying the https page?

Comment: Right Tiggerito, My purpose is to be ecological on this site. It works as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problems with https vs http for websites with little domain authority, or for websites which link to a checkout with https and then link back out to https instead of http.

We recommend clients to 301 to the http version just in case this causes issues.

Try this Mod Rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```